# MacBook Pro repeatedly plays boot sound and occasionally shows apple logo, but will not actually boot

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup

Shut down my macbook pro (2019, BigSur) last night and tried to turn it back on. It booted into my bootcamp windows, so I tried switching back to osx, but it would just play the bootup sound at 20-40 s intervals on a blank screen. I could get out of that by pressing option and loading back into windows. I tried doing an internet recovery cause I saw it as a fix somewhere, but that failed, error -2003F.

After the internet recovery, it now won't boot into osx or windows, and sometimes the apple logo pops up. It will continue to play the boot sound even if I have the laptop closed. I can still press option to open the bootcamp menu, but no other keyboard inputs seem to do anything during boot. I've tried resetting the PRAM, a regular (non internet) recovery, safe mode. None of them seemed to change anything. The only thing that stops it from looping is turning it off by holding the power button, but it acts the same when I turn it on.

I'm not very experienced with fixing these things, and I can't find any other forum posts that describe a similar looping.

Comment: Which specific Macbook Pro model is this?

Comment: If you try booting in Verbose Mode (CMD + V during boot) do you see boot console text? If so, can you capture a slow-motion video and upload individual framegrabs?